# how to fix RadioButton's width, so the widget wouldnot depend on text size

Tags: java, android

I have a horizontal RadioGroup and RadioButtons

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/tab_messages"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_tabbar"

            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        >

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_messages"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text="long long long text"
            />
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_contacts"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text="shorter"

            />
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_search"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text="short short"
            />
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_settings"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text=";("

            />

</RadioGroup>

<style name="Tab" >
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">-6dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:button">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:drawableTop">@android:drawable/btn_radio</item>
    </style>
```

and i got this (Screenshot): http://c.kurganec.ru/p/jv8Ppzq.png

seems like layout_weight parameter works as not as i expect.
I wish the tabs were the same size (f.e. 1/4 of display width)
Is it posible?

Comment: `layout_weight` works fine, and will solve your problem, but you have to actually apply it to each child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/tab_messages"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            >
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_messages"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="long long long text" android:layout_width="1dip"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_contacts"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text="shorter"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="1dip"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_search"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text="short short"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="1dip"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_settings"
            style="@style/Tab"
            android:text=";("
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="1dip"/>
</RadioGroup>
```